# Using Spring Security authorization with context-specific authorities

Tags: spring-security

We need to add access control to our application, making sure that every command is performed by a user who has the proper authorities for the given domain objects.  We are already using Spring Security 4.0 for authentication and intend to use it for authorization as well.

What makes this complex is the way that authorities are granted to a given user.  In our problem space, a User can found several Companies and hire other Users, making them Employees.  Each User can be an Employee of several Companies.  Some authorities can be granted to a User directly (e.g. canResetOtherUserPassword); other authorities can also be granted by a Company to an Employee based on their Role in the Company (e.g. canOpenProject, canRenameProject).  When performing Company-independent commands, User-specific authorities must be checked by the service layer.  When performing Company-specific commands (e.g. open a project for a company, rename an existing project), Employee-specific authorities must be checked.

Now let's consider these last two commands, which would have the following service signatures:

```
long openProject(long companyId, String title)
void renameProject(long projectId, String title)
```

To control access for the 1st method, the authorization component could retrieve the acting User through the thread-local SecurityContext.authentication, retrieve the Company using the companyId parameter, retrieve the Employee corresponding to the current User, then match Employee-specific authorities against the required canOpenProject authority.

To control access for the 2nd method, the authorization component could again retrieve the acting User through the Thread-local SecurityContext.authentication, retrieve the Project using the projectId, retrieve the owner Company through project.ownerCompanyId, retrieve the Employee corresponding to the current User, then match Employee-specific authorities against the required canRenameProject.

Clearly, this can be done using procedural code, as I just described.  We would prefer to use a declarative approach similar to the @PreAuthorize interceptor that Spring Security already offers, and obviously to write as little code as possible.  We just don't know where to start.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can implement UserDetails (org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails) or just extend a default implementation of UserDetails, like User (org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User) ---> CustomUserDetails with additional attributes like company (with getters).

finally : use simply @PreAuthorize("principal.company.companyId == #companyId")

Reference : [Spring Security 3.1](http://www.amazon.fr/Spring-Security-3-1-Robert-Winch/dp/1849518262) chapter 10 (you need to go back to chapter 3 for UserDetails implementation)
It was very useful for me !

Comment: Thanks for the pointers to the reference documentation. The issue is that sometimes I don't have a companyId parameter, such as in the renameProject method.  I guess I will have to resort to implementing custom PermissionEvaluators.